# Validation with one radio button option only

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation

I have a radiobuttonlist with three choices.  When a user clicks on the "Provided" option, two textboxes open underneath it. These two are required when selecting that option. How can I require these two only when that option is marked but not if it isn't and still allow me to process the form? I tried using `ValidationGroup`, but since I am still new to developing, I think I am missing something. Any guidance would be appreciated, thanks in advance!

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblCreat" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" CssClass="rblMargin rblCreat">
    <asp:ListItem>N/A</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>DIC to Obtain</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Provided</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>
<div style="display: none;" id="provided-fields">
    <br />
    <p style="margin-left: 250px">
        Results:
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCreatResults" runat="server" Width="99px" TabIndex="21" Height="22px"
            CssClass="margin"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvResults" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCreatResults"
            ErrorMessage="*Required" ValidationGroup="provided"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
        <br />
        Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtCreatDate" runat="server" Width="99px" TabIndex="22" onkeydown="return DateFormat(this, event.keyCode)"
            Height="22px"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="rfvDate" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtCreatDate"
            ErrorMessage="*Required" ValidationGroup="provided"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Your code Behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    rblCreat.Items[0].Attributes.Add("onclick", "abc('1');");
    rblCreat.Items[1].Attributes.Add("onclick", "abc('2');");
    rblCreat.Items[2].Attributes.Add("onclick", "abc('3');");
}
```

---

### Your Java Script

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function abc(ID) {
        if (ID == '3') {
            var btn = document.getElementById("<%=btn.ClientID%>");
            btn.onclick = function () {
                WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(btn.id, "", true, "provided", "", false, false));
            }
            document.getElementById('providedfields').style.display = 'block';
        }
        if (ID == '1' || ID == '2') {
            var btn = document.getElementById("<%=btn.ClientID%>");
            btn.onclick = function () {
                WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions(btn.id, "", true, "newValGroup", "", false, false));
            }
            document.getElementById('providedfields').style.display = 'none';
        }
    }
</script>
```

---

### Your HTML

```
<asp:radiobuttonlist id="rblCreat" runat="server" repeatdirection="Horizontal" cssclass="rblMargin rblCreat">
        <asp:ListItem Value="1">N/A</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="2">DIC to Obtain</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem Value="3">Provided</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:radiobuttonlist>
<div style="display: none;" id="providedfields">
    <br />
    <p style="margin-left: 250px">
        Results:
        <asp:textbox id="txtCreatResults" runat="server" width="99px" tabindex="21" height="22px"
            cssclass="margin"></asp:textbox>
        <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="rfvResults" runat="server" controltovalidate="txtCreatResults"
            errormessage="*Required" validationgroup="provided"></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
        <br />
        Date:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <asp:textbox id="txtCreatDate" runat="server" width="99px" tabindex="22" height="22px"></asp:textbox>
        <asp:requiredfieldvalidator id="rfvDate" runat="server" controltovalidate="txtCreatDate"
            errormessage="*Required" validationgroup="provided"></asp:requiredfieldvalidator>
    </p>
</div>
<asp:button id="btn" validationgroup="provided" runat="server" />
```

---

When you click on the button it will postback in case of other then provided options.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a [CustomValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eee01cx.aspx) could help you with this.

```
<asp:CustomValidator 
runat="server" 
id="cusCustom" 
controltovalidate="txtCreatDate" 
onservervalidate="cusCustom_ServerValidate" 
errormessage="You must enter a text." />
```

and then write the method in your code behind with whatever logic you might need.

```
 protected void cusCustom_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (rblCreat.SelectedIndex == 1)
        {
            if (e.Value.Length > 0)
            {
                e.IsValid = true;
            }
            else
            {
                e.IsValid = false;
            }
        }
        else {
            e.IsValid = true;
        }
    }
```

Note: This is not written in any IDE so I can't be sure about the syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Before processing the form, you could check (from the server code) whether the required option in the radiobuttonlist is checked. If not, set the Enabled property of the requiredfieldvalidators to False.